# Read Characteristic from rxBleDevice gives exception in Android, in iOS why it works fine using same UUID

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-android, rxandroidble

Currently i am working with an application where it involves reading data from the ble device. I am trying to read data from Andesfit Thermometer, Andesfit Blood Pressure, Andesfit Body Weight Scale.

For that i need to notify using Characteristic UUID. The notification stuff works fine and i am receiving data properly when any of the devices emits data.

Think about a situation where the user has already taken a measurement using the blood pressure machine. Then he picked up his device, got connected. I should be able to retrieve the last record and show it in the device.

In order to show the last record i need to read the characteristic using UUID

**In iOS i am can retrieve the last record & notify using the same characteristic UUID and it is working fine.**

```
 characteristic UUID is 2A1C

 peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
 peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
```

**But in Android if i try to read using the characteristic UUID that used for notify it gives me exception.**

```
rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false, Timeout(12000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .flatMapSingle { rxBleConnection ->

                    rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("00002a1c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
                        .subscribe({bytes ->

                    },{t: Throwable? ->
                        var mess = t!!.localizedMessage
                        t.printStackTrace()
                    })
```

Exception message is

**GATT exception from MAC address F4:5E:AB:0D:7B:93, with type BleGattOperation{description='CHARACTERISTIC_READ'}**

**Here is my service discovery operation in Android**

In my service discovery i can clearly see that this characteristic UUID is just meant for notify.

```
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: Primary Service - Health Thermometer (00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: Instance ID: 51
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: -> Characteristics:
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:  * Temperature Measurement (00002a1c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    Properties: [ INDICATE ]
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    -> Descriptors: 
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Client Characteristic Configuration (00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Characteristic Presentation Format (00002904-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:  * Temperature Type (00002a1d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    Properties: [ READ ]
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:  * Intermediate Temperature (00002a1e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    Properties: [ NOTIFY ]
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    -> Descriptors: 
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Client Characteristic Configuration (00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:  * Measurement Interval (00002a21-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    Properties: [ READ WRITE INDICATE ]
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    -> Descriptors: 
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Client Characteristic Configuration (00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Valid Range (00002906-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: Primary Service - Battery Service (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: Instance ID: 65
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: -> Characteristics:
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:  * Battery Level (00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    Properties: [ READ NOTIFY ]
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:    -> Descriptors: 
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Client Characteristic Configuration (00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation:      * Report Reference (00002908-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
V/RxBle#ServiceDiscoveryOperation: --------------- ====== Finished peripheral content ====== ---------------
```

Answer (score 1):

> why it works fine using same UUID (on iOS and on Android it does not)?

As you can see the characteristic you want to read has property [INDICATE] and not [READ]. Android OS checks permissions of the characteristic before performing an operation on it and does not allow to start one if the target characteristic does not have a corresponding property. iOS on the other hand executes the operation and the peripheral may (or may not) accept it regardless of this characteristic properties.